# Conditionally add pseudo-class on hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to use styled-components and I need a way to conditionally add a pseudo-class on hover.

Here is an example of my code:

```
buildRating(numberRating, totalRating) {
  const Star = styled.div`
    display: inline;

    div&:hover:before {
      color: ${Colors.goldColor};
    }
    &:before {
      unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
      direction: ltr;
      content: '\\2605';
      color: ${props =>
        props.hasColorStar ? Colors.goldColor : Colors.blackColor};
    }
  `;

  const ratings = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < totalRating; i++) {
    ratings.push(
      i < numberRating ? <Star key={i} hasColorStar /> : <Star key={i} />,
    );
  }
  return ratings;
}
```

Now the above styled-component will generate:

```
/* sc-component-id: sc-iwsKbI */
.sc-iwsKbI {
}
.NnxkP {
  display: inline;
}
div.NnxkP:hover:before {
  color: #f6a128;
}
.NnxkP:before {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: ltr;
  content: "\2605";
  color: #363636;
}

/* sc-component-id: sc-gZMcBi */
.sc-gZMcBi {
}
.dBzcSQ {
  display: inline;
}
div.dBzcSQ:hover:before {
  color: #f6a128;
}
.dBzcSQ:before {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: ltr;
  content: "\2605";
  color: #f6a128;
}
```

I don't want it to generate:

```
div.dBzcSQ:hover:before {
  color: #f6a128;
}
```

Is there a way to use the below styled-component

```
div&:hover:before {
   color: ${Colors.goldColor};
}
```

when `props.hasColorStar` is true?

Is there a way of accomplishing this with styled-components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a props `hasColorStar` and want to conditional apply the style based on it, you can do something as below:

```
 const Star = styled.div`
    ...
    ${({ hasColorStar }) => hasColorStar && `
      div&:hover:before {
        color: ${Colors.goldColor};
      }
    `}
    ...
 `;
```

Comment: Putting a template literal inside a template literal looks very strange and it seems to confuse VSCode with formatting.   However, it works!

Comment: It does confuse VSCode, however, it's pretty common when it comes to `styled-components` or other css-in-js library that based on string literal such as `emotion`. If you want to give it a better format, move the function out of the string literal and assign it to a constant.

Comment: Great idea moving it to it's own variable.   I'll also check out emotion because i've never heard of it.